# using mod wsgi & apache, images only get served if in a sub directory

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, file-permissions

I am setting up a django site using python2.7, apache2.2, mod_wsgi4.4, and django1.8. I'm having a very weird error when trying to serve simple static images. My project root is located at `/var/www/siteName/` and all of my static files are being served from `/var/www/siteName/static/`. I have a small hierarchy of files within `.../static/` to organize all the site's images. The file tree looks like this:

- static

  - images

    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    - 4
  - monitor //css files for all my pages

My Problem is that I'm able to serve images that are located within the numbered directories but not any images that are located directly in the `images` directory. I can't figure out why. Moving an image file from `images` to `images/3/` works..but I don't want to have to do that. Any time that I attempt to access an image file in `static` I get slapped by this error message

> (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/siteName/static/images/groupshot.jpg

Hardcoding the paths into the .html template gives the same results:

```
<div class="imageContainer">
<img src='/static/images/3/stethoscope/groupshot.jpg'>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
<img src='/static/images/groupshot.jpg'>
</div>
```

The first img tag works fine while the second doesn't.

Below is the virtualhost definition from my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/siteName/projName/wsgi.py
         Alias /static/ /var/www/siteName/static/
<Directory /var/www/siteName/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/siteName/projName>
       <Files wsgi.py>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
       </Files>
</Directory>
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/www/siteName/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/siteName/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Has anyone else seen anything like this? I've checked and double checked using a tool called `namei` all the file permissions. Most of the static files are owned by root:root. Directories are 755 and files have 644 permissions.

output of `namei -l static/images/3/stethoscope/groupshot.jpg`:

```
f: static/images/3/stethoscope/groupshot.jpg
drwxr-xr-x root root static
drwxr-xr-x root root images
drwxr-xr-x root root 3
drwxr-xr-x root root stethoscope
-rw-r--r-- root root groupshot.jpg
```

output of `namei -l static/images/groupshot.jpg`:

```
drwxr-xr-x root root static
drwxr-xr-x root root images
-rw-r--r-- root root groupshot.jpg
```

Comment: "Directories are 755 and files have 644 permissions" -- which directories? All of them? And the files?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question to show which directories i meant. When I saw the permission denied error I went straight to [this apache wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FileSystemPermissions) to double check.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research I came across [this article by Pete Freitag](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/793.cfm). It seems that this was an SELinux issue. I used `chcon` to set the proper security context for my static files. In my case, since I had a working sub directory I used that directory as a reference for the parent:

`sudo chcon -R --reference=/var/www/siteName/static/images/3 /var/www/siteName/static`

and that did the trick!